# How do we know $b$ is in $G$?

Tags: group-theory

I'm having trouble understanding when we can assume that an element is in a group.

**Given problem**

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Prove that if $ab \in H$, then $ba \in H$.

**Given solution**

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and suppose $ab \in H$; say $ab = h \in H$.  Since $H$ is normal, $H$ is closed under conjugation by elements of $G$. In particular, $bhb^{-1} \in H$. Substituting $h=ab$, we see that $babb^{-1} = ba \in H$.

**Question**

Why can we assume $b \in G$?

My understanding is that even if the product of two elements is in a group, we can't necessarily assume that the *individual* elements are also in that group. I'd assume that the same goes for large groups also, i.e., $ab \in G \nRightarrow a,b \in G$.

Comment: Because all your elements need to be taken from $G$; otherwise, the entire problem doesn't make sense from the start. So $a$ and $b$ are assumed to be elements of $G$, as understood from context.

Comment: A more pedantic wording of the original problem would have said something like "Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and let $a, b \in G$.  Prove ...".  However, even as written, context makes clear that $a,b \in G$ (where else could they come from?)

Comment: What you label "your understanding" is true for *subgroups*; however, there needs to be a contextual set-with-an-operation from which everything is taken. In some cases this context need not be clear (for example, if we are talking about addition of integers, is our group the integers, the rationals, the reals, the complex numbers, some other set?), in which case it needs to be specified explicitly where the elements are being taken from. But here the only possible context is $G$. So there is an implicity "if $a,b\in G$ are such that" in between "Prove that" and "$ab\in H$".

Comment: All very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your binary group operation $\cdot$ is only defined on $G$.  That is, its domain is $G \times G$.  When you write $ab$, this a shorthand for $a \cdot b$.  But then for the expression to make sense, $a$ and $b$ must be in $G$.  Therefore it's a literature convention to *imply* that by writing $a\cdot b \in H$, we actually mean "$a \in G, b \in G, a \cdot b \in H$".

Note that is very different than saying that "$a\cdot b \in H$" implies "$a\in H, b \in H, ab \in H$", because $\cdot$ is well-defined on a superset of $H \times H$.  So, usually literature just implies the minimal requirement for the expression to make sense, that is, $a$ and $b$ are in $G$.